# Flutter: ListView maximum height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can set a minimum height doing something like this:
 ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: listItems.toList(),
          );

But how could I have a maximum height to have for example max 3 elements displayed? (to see the rest I'd have to scroll)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap your ListView with a SizedBox, like this :

```
SizedBox(
    height: 300,
        child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
                SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
                SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
                SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
            ],
          ),),
```

**Edit :**
If you want the container to shrink when there is less than 3 items, set the maxHeight constraint for the container and `shrinkWrap: true` for the ListView :

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.red)),
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300),
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
      SizedBox(height: 100, child: Placeholder()),
    ],
  )
),
```

Comment: I was looking for some ListView parameters but I guess I could wrap it with some sized widget

Comment: trying this is not exactly what I meant. If we set 300px height, we'll always have that fixed size but I'm aiming for a responsive list. If I have 1-2-3 elements the size will be number of elements but more than than it will have a scroll. It's like `max-height` and `height` in css